# Autofac - Resolve parameters at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have this tiered structure

```
namespace DataAccess 

public class SqlDataContext : ISqlDataContext
{
    public SqlDataContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionFactory = CreateConnection(connectionString);
    }
}


namespace Repositories

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(ISqlDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _db = dataContext;
    }
}

namespace Core

public class UserManager :IUserManager
{
    public UserManager(UserRepository repository)
   {
        _userRepository = repository;
    }
}
```

then I register this in the Autofac container like this

```
        builder.Register((a, b) => new SqlDataContext(b.Named<string>("connectionString")))
            .As<ISqlDataContext>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>()
            .As<IUserRepository>()
            .WithParameter((x, o) => x.Name == "dataContext", (x, o) => o.Resolve<ISqlDataContext>());

        builder.RegisterType<UserManager>()
            .As<IUserManager>()
            .WithParameter((x, o) => x.Name == "userRepository", (x, o) => o.Resolve<IUserRepository>());
```

Then I call this in my client

```
      namespace Client

     internal void OnConnectionStringResolved() {

        var connectionString = GetConnectionString();

        var dbContext = DependencyResolver.Instance().Resolve<ISqlDataContext>(
            new NamedParameter("connectionString", connectionString)
            );

         var userRepository = 
             DependencyResolver.Instance().Resolve<IUserRepository>(
            new NamedParameter("dbContext", dbContext)
            );

        _userManager = DependencyResolver.Instance().Resolve<IUserManager>(
            new NamedParameter("userRepository", userRepository)
            );

       var user = _userManager.GetUser(userId);
     }
```

I don't want to DataAccess projet to be referenced in my Client project. But the problem is that the ConnectionString can only be resolved at Runtime.

I was thinking in my client the call should be something like this

```
       _userManager = DependencyResolver.Instance().Resolve<IUserManager>(GetConnectionString());
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you create an options interface that can be passed in at an acceptable point?

Comment: [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) might be helpful.